# Css print - duplicate images for printing

Tags: css, image, printing

I've got a website with hundreds of colour images, and am currently in the process of creating print optimized versions of the pages.

The images are important to the information and thus need to be printed with the pages, but since they're in full colour I've duplicated them as grayscale. Since duplicating all those images eats up quiet a bit of server storage, my problem is that in order to use them for `css` print media I'll also need to duplicate all the web pages (in the hundred) since `css` background images don't print, and at first I thought I could've simply replaced the full colour images with `css` background-image and visibility: hidden, for the colour images, then learned backgrounds don't print.

So, my question is is the only option in this case to duplicate all images and all web pages and create a whole new directory of the site specific for print, or is there a way to save space, that still prints reliably?

The rest of the webpage contents are dealt with the standard `css` way for print, it's just the images that are the crux, as they're so many, and by default would waste a lot of printer ink, thus have to be grayscale where their background colour is replaced with white.

Also, is it common for sites to have duplicate directories, such as one for screen, one for print?

Edit (based on initial answers). The images are opaque, and each page has a lot of images (it's basically image based content), so the only solution I saw was to edit their colors so their opaque becomes white and vice versa. I guess it means creating a duplicate site's the only option.

Comment: try `filter:grayscale(1)` within your print-preview

Comment: have you tried `@media print { img { filter: grayscale(100%); } }` ?

Comment: Well, I thought of that, but the images are solid color and plenty per page, plus as i mentioned part of the content so it'd mean a lot of ink if I didn't change their colors for print. Now they're mostly white, which works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can only answer and not comment as my rep is low :(

Why would you go to all of this trouble when the end user has the option anyway to print in greyscale?
Saving your user a few pence on printer ink will not get you brownie points

Comment: Since each page contains a lot of images that'd need to be printed, and are solid color, so it means greyscale or not it'd mean a lot of ink, that's why I swapped their colors so their backgrounds are now white (which fortunately works).